# Word to describe something that is about to become trending?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Swedish there exists a word called *bubblare*. This word describes something that is about to get popular or up-and-coming. Is there an English equivalent to this?

The word **trending** is kind of what I am looking for, but the state right before it actually takes off. Something is going to become a trend but havent't yet.

An example:
A music program lists the top 5 most popular songs every week. In addition to this list there is also one song that is guessed to become popular enough to enter this list in the near future. This song is called *bubblare*.

Comment: The word **emerging** corresponds to *up-and-coming*, but hasn't a *popular* connotation.

Comment: In regard to actors, we use the term "rising star".  In regard to a song making its way up the "charts", possibly on its way to being a "hit", it's referred to as (ranking #) **with a bullet**

Comment: Used to be "camp" was the term.  But that's no longer trending.

Comment: I'd go with _verging_ or (even better) _cusping_, which has the advantage of not being widely used to mean anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [**nascent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nascent)?

> (Especially of a process or organization) just coming into existence and beginning to display signs of future potential:

Comment: I believe this is the most fitting word for my preferences even though it isn't exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you gave us a sentence example, it might be easier to tell what you're going for.

Here are a few possibilities:

- **burgeoning**: meaning "growing rapidly", often applied to things growing in popularity or acclaim
- **trending**: very modern and specific to things that are growing in popularity, used mostly in technology
- **rising**: often in relation to people growing in popularity, "a rising star in the business world"
- **bubbling**: referring to something that's simmering, about to boil-over

And some idioms, if you prefer:

- **gaining momentum**
- **gain steam**

Comment: I updated my question with a better description

Answer (score 1):

The word "rising" may be a good synonym, depending on context.

For example, when a performer is growing in popularity, we might say, "S/he is a rising star."

It is more likely, however, to be used in reference to people or entities (like businesses) than objects. Again, one might say, "XYZ Corporation is a rising business in the world of ABC." But generally, we'd not say, "Sole is the producer of rising BShoes, the next big thing in footwear."

Answer (score 1):

[Trending](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=trending%20meaning) is the common social media term.

verb
gerund or present participle: trending

1. change or develop in a general direction.
   "unemployment has been trending upward"
   synonyms:   move, go, head, drift, gravitate, swing, shift, turn, incline, tend, lean, veer
   "interest rates are trending up"
   (especially of geographical features) bend or turn away in a specified direction.
   "the Richelieu River trends northward to Lake Champlain"
2. (of a topic) be the subject of many posts on a social media website within a short period of time.
   "I've just taken a quick look at what's trending on Twitter right now"

[#trending](https://twitter.com/hashtag/trending?lang=en)

[Facebook Trending](https://www.facebook.com/help/1401671260054622)

[YouTube TopTrending](https://www.youtube.com/user/TopTrendingTV)

[Etsy Trending](https://www.etsy.com/trending)

[NY Times Trending](http://www.nytimes.com/trending/)

[BBC Trending](http://www.bbc.com/news/blogs/trending)

Comment: [Jinx!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children%27s_game)) +1 for giving the same answer as me.

Answer (score 0):

you might say **"a forthcoming fad"**

> - [**"forthcoming"**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=forthcoming+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=4yXKVenfK6Gk8weP8KWwCA&gws_rd=ssl) (adj) - about to happen in the near future.
> - [**"fad"**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=forthcoming+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=4yXKVenfK6Gk8weP8KWwCA&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=fad) (noun) - an intense and widely shared enthusiasm for something, especially one that is short-lived and without basis in the object's qualities; a craze.

e.g.

- The forthcoming elections, forthcoming cultural attractions, etc.
- When I was a young girl, no fad was more popular than the hula hoop.

Answer (score 0):

A common word used online is ***trending*** to indicate something is becoming noteworthy. The word *trendy* means something that is currently popular.

> Of or in accord with the latest fad or fashion: *trendy clothes*.
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trendy)</sub>

---

You have since edited your question title as a way to dismiss *trending* as the word you are looking for. But I think you are misunderstanding how the word is used.

Technically, *trending* can mean either up or down. But, it's current usage by online sites is always taken to mean in the upward direction. When tracking trends, these sites use statistical measurements to decide if something is about to become more popular than it already is. If something already has a mass following in the millions, then an upward tick of 1000 additional hits would hardly be worth mentioning. But, if something only has a following in the tens of thousands, then an upward tick or 1000 is noteworthy, and the item would show up as *trending*.

Thus, the only known state for something that is about to become trending is that its popularity is *stable* and *relatively unknown*. At the moment the popularity moves upward from what it is, it becomes *trending*. When it reaches a critical mass of followers, it is considered *popular*.

For your song example, there is really no telling how a station decided a song was *bubblare*. On American radio, I would say this is analogous to "*feature* a song," or "put a *spotlight* on a song." This is more a marketing tool than a measurement of what is about to become popular. Producers try to influence stations to give their artists air time to promote their songs in the hopes it will make their artists popular (and them money).

Comment: The word I am looking for is the state right before something becomes popular though :(

Comment: Something can't become popular unless people know about it. Once people become aware of it, that thing is *trending*.

Comment: Added example to clarify

Comment: If the song wasn't trending, the only people listening to it would be the people already listening to it. The fact that more people are starting to listen is *trending*.

Comment: Perhaps your update is more fitting of an answer rather than what I am looking for. Spotlight or feature that is. Makes more sense in my context when I think about it.